# CSP: Refused to execute inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy, nonce

What am I doing wrong?
For some reason, CSP blocks the js file call anyway, even though I specified nonce ID in attr.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'nonce-Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu';">
</head>
```

Call Function:

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {

jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true,
        scriptAttrs: { nonce: "Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu" }
    });
}

$.loadScript("/js/temp.js");
```

Error message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'nonce-Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu'". Either the 'unsafe-inline'
>   keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-9pSu4Q2RG6fzg6RdmNxg1z3W+Y9EdC0f90RGYsLO/o4='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Jquery ver:
`/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */`

Edited:
if i dont use `$.loadScript` function, all js files with installed nonce attr works GOOD.
The problem is in the dynamic call of the js file, but unfortunately I can not get rid of it. And it needs to be loaded dynamically.

Edited(2):
I tried through document.createElement ("script"), also through jQuery.globalEval and added nonce everywhere. The output turns out so that some functions (one of them uses foreach) do not work with an error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`
Through the console in the "Network" tab, I see the loaded script.

Dont work --->

```
jQuery.globalEval($.loadScript("/js/temp.js"), {
    nonce: "Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu"
});
```

Dont work again --->

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "/js/temp.js";
scriptTag.setAttribute("nonce", "Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu");
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptTag);
```

If i delete meta Content-Security-Policy - All codes above work. All scripts work as needed)

Comment: Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: I test this only on Chrome. Because my software uses the Chromium engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. Thanks to the jquery developers.
As it turned out, everything was initially clear, but I just did not notice it, because my code is too big.
The problem was in the DOM onevent handlers, and in my case, onclick event on DIV.

```
<div onclick="setContent('content1')">1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [current documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the property to set attributes on the script tag is called `scriptAttrs`.

> **scriptAttrs**
>
> Type: PlainObject
>
> Defines an object with additional attributes to be used in a "script" or "jsonp" request. The key represents the name of the attribute and the value is the attribute's value. If this object is provided it will force the use of a script-tag transport. For example, this can be used to set nonce, integrity, or crossorigin attributes to satisfy Content Security Policy requirements. (version added: 3.4.0)

I suggest you try

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true,
        scriptAttrs: { nonce: "Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu" }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have already noticed this and corrected it myself. But it did not help.

I tried through document.createElement ("script"), also through jQuery.globalEval and added nonce everywhere. The output turns out so that some functions (one of them uses foreach) do not work with an error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:" script-src 'nonce-Xiojd98a8jd3s9kFiDi29Uijwdu' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256 -...'), or a nonce ('nonce -...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: Through the console in the "Network" tab, I see the loaded script.